# lost my iphone development certificates and private key

Tags: iphone, ios

I lost the certificate the private key everything

I did everything from scratch as per the manual that is i started with the certificate process till the end but still i have the same problem when i choose to install the application into the iPhone device.

Here is the problem message when i click into Any iOS device in the info icon.

The name ("common name") of a valid code-signing certificate in a keychain within your keychain pah. A missing or invalid certificate will cause a build error. [CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY]

Answer (score 0):

Add the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Authority Certificate

Answer (score 0):

login to [the iphone developer portal](http://developer.apple.com) all the certificates/profiles can be found there or if in need be regenerated